# How to format the way dictionaries print in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I am trying to understand how to print this dictionary to look something like this:

```
color: red
name: volvo
```

However, the output is returning:

```
{'color': 'red', 'name': 'volvo'}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `join()` and an f-string:

```
>>> d = {'car': 'red', 'name': 'volvo'}
>>> print("\n".join(f"{k}: {v}" for k, v in d.items()))
car: red
name: volvo
```

or with a `for` loop and multiple `print`s:

```
>>> for k, v in d.items():
...     print(f"{k}: {v}")
...
car: red
name: volvo
```